# Implementing ngInfiniteScroll to a $http service

Tags: angularjs, infinite-scroll

I have the following service fetching data from an external API:

```
$scope.getDetails = function (id) {
  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.artist = data;
    });
  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=12').
    success(function(data2) {
        $scope.releases = data2.releases;
    });
  $scope.clicked = true;
  $scope.sliding = true;
}
```

And it populates here with ng-repeat:

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="ImageCtrl" ng-repeat="release in releases | filter:album | filter:year | filter:{ role: \'main\' }">
  <div class="release"><img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{image}}" />           
    {{release.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been checking the [documentation of ngInfiniteScroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/documentation.html) but I don't see very clearly how could I implement it.

Should I basically make a releases?page=1++ when the page hits bottom?

I've also seen the example based on $http from the ngInfiniteScroll site, but it's a tad over my current knowledge and I wouldn't know how to adapt it to my code.

Any hints?

**EDIT**: I've used hassassins answer to create the following code, but is still not operational. Have I missed something?

```
$scope.getDetails = function (id) {
  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.artist = data;
    });
  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=12').
    success(function(data2) {
        $scope.releases = data2.releases;
  });  

  var _page = 0;
  $scope.releases = [];
  $scope.LoadDetails = function(id) {
      _page++;
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=' + _page + '&per_page=12').then(function(data2) {
          $scope.releases = $scope.data2.releases;
      });
  };    
  $scope.clicked = true;
  $scope.sliding = true;
}
```

Notice that I include the the Release $http query twice, first to call the first batch of releases, and then inside the LoadDetails function!

Also, here's a [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0aYg1TbnRFwW1WhuPKYp?p=preview)!

Answer (score 3):

Infinite scrolls work by listening to scroll events on an element and, if you are within a certain distance of the bottom, call a callback. The callback will load in more results (in your case through `$http`. So you could set up your infinite scroll like this:

```
// In your controller
var _page = 0;
$scope.releases = [];
$scope.LoadDetails = function() {
    _page++;
    $http.get('/endpoint/?page=' + _page /* ... whatever else you need */).then(function(data) {
        $scope.releases = $scope.releases.concat(data);
    });
};

// In your dom
<div infinite-scroll="LoadDetails()">
    <div ng-repeat="release in releases"> {{release}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [link to their demo](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html)

As for implementing it you can check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/), where a basic infinite scroll is implemented.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks hassassin! I've tried your code (see in the updated question) but it's not working, so maybe i've missed something! Care to take a look? Thanks again! Eric

Comment: The idea is that you have one function, which fetches results. So when the list is first loaded, the infinite scroll will call that function and grab the first page of results (say 1-12). Then if you scroll down, the same function is called to load the second page (say 13-24). When that data is returned, you add that to your releases array, which will update the ng-repeat